# Object level authorisations or ACLs in Google Shared drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

Does Google Shared drive have any object level authorizations or ACLs ?

Currently i only see that there are members of the shared drive and they get apply to all the files and folders in the shared drive.

How do i achieve the following scenario ?

Shared Drive 1

- Folder 1

  - File 1
- Folder 2

  - File 2

I want user A to have access to Folder 1 under Shared Drive 1 and user B to user access to Folder 2. But it seems its not possible in Google shared drive.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder under a Shared Drive if you right click on that designated folder and click on the Share Button. Here are a list of scenarios that will happen once it is done:

- The user will be notified via email that the folder has been shared.
- The user will not have any visibility on the source Shared Drive where that designated folder is located. He will simply have access to the folder and all of its contents.

Another important note to consider for you to be able to achieve this:

1. Make sure that the Shared drive settings option is set to allow "People who aren't shared drive members can be added to files".

[image]

2. This can be done through the Google Workspace Admin Console under Apps > Google Workspace > Drives and Docs > Manage shared drives. And, on the list of Shared Drives, you should see the settings when you hover over the items on the Shared Drive list.

[image]

**Reference:**
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7662202?hl=en#zippy=%2Crestrict-access-for-an-existing-shared-drive

For further assistance regarding this matter I'd best advise you to contact [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)